# Laravel routing for deleting one record

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel (but not developing) and am following along in the free Laravel 6 from Scratch course at Laracasts. I can't afford to subscribe to Laracasts so I can't ask questions there.

I've been following along as the instructor build an app that listed a bunch of articles, displayed a single article, created and saved a new article, and edited an existing article and saved it back to the database. Now I'm trying to delete an individual record but I can't quite get it right.

On the page where I display a single record, I give the user the option of editing the record or of deleting the record via two separate links. The Edit process works fine: it displays the record, allows me to change it (assuming I pass the validations), and then saves it to the database correctly.

The delete process fails. Since I am already displaying the record to the user and have presumably satisfied themselves that it IS the record they want to delete, I want to simply go to the destroy() method of my controller. But I'm obviously doing it wrong. I *think* the code in the controller is correct so it may be the routes that are messed up. The course doesn't show you how to do a delete and of the videos and stack overflow articles I've seen use different techniques, none of which I fully understand. I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. There can't be more than 1 or 2 lines that are wrong....

Here's the message I get when I click on the Delete button when I am displaying Article #6:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
http://localhost:8000/articles/6/delete
```

Here's my routing:

```
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
Route::get('/articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
Route::put('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
Route::post('/articles/{article}/delete', 'ArticlesController@destroy');
```

Here's the page that displays the article and let's the user click Edit or Delete links:

```
@extends ('layout');

@section ('content');

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            <span class="byline">{{ $article->author}}</span></div>
        <p><img src="{{ $article->photopath}}" alt="" class="image image-full" /> </p>
        <p>{{ $article->body }}
        <p><a class="article-link" href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/edit">Edit This Article</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="article-link" href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/delete">Delete This Article</a></p>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Lastly, here's my ArticlesController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::latest()->paginate(2);
    return view ('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
}

public function show(Article $article) 
{
    return view('articles.show', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function create() 
{
    return view('articles.create');
}

public function store() 
{
    //Stores a NEW article
    Article::create($this->validateArticle());
    return redirect('/articles');
}   

public function edit(Article $article) 
{
    return view('articles.edit', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function update(Article $article)
{
    //Updates an EXISTING article
    $article->update($this->validateArticle());
    return redirect('/articles/'.$article->id);
}

public function validateArticle()
{
    return request()->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:20'],
        'author' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:30'],
        'photopath' => ['required', 'min:10', 'max:100'],
        'excerpt' => ['required', 'min:10', 'max:50'],
        'body' => ['required', 'min:50', 'max:500']
    ]);
}

public function delete(Article $article)
{
    return view('articles.delete', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function destroy(Article $article)
{
    $article = Article::find($article->id);
    $article->delete();
    return redirect('/articles');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Blade file
@extends('layouts.backend.app')

@section('title','Article')

@push('css')
<link href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="block-header">
        <h2>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('admin.tag.create') }}">
            <i class="material-icons">add</i>
        {{ __('ADD ARTICLE') }}
        </a>            
        </h2>
    </div>

    <!-- Exportable Table -->
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.tag.index') }}">
                            {{ __('ALL ARTICLE') }}
                            <span class="btn btn-warning sm">{{ $articles->count() }}</span>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>{{__('Sl')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Name')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Slug')}}</th>
                                <th>i{{__('Post Count')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Create At')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Action')}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{__('Sl')}}</th>
                                    <th>{{__('Name')}}</th>
                                    <th>{{__('Slug')}}</th>
                                    <th>{{__('Post Count')}}</th>
                                    <th>{{__('Create At')}}</th>
                                    <th>{{__('Action')}}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                               @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1)
                                   @foreach($articles as $key=>$article)
                                       <tr>
                                           <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
                                           <td>{{ $article->name }}</td>
                                           <td>{{ $article->slug }}</td>
                                           <td>{{ $article->posts->count() }}</td>
                                           <td>{{ $article->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                           <td >
                                               <a href="{{ route('admin.$article.edit',$article->id) }}" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">
                                                   <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                               </a>
                                               <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" type="button" onclick="deletearticle({{ $article->id }})">
                                                   <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                                               </button>
                                               <form id="delete-form-{{ $article->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.article.destroy',$article->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                   @csrf
                                                   @method('DELETE')
                                               </form>
                                           </td>
                                       </tr>
                                   @endforeach
                                @else
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #END# Exportable Table -->
</div>
@endsection


@push('js')
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.flash.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/jszip.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/pdfmake.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/vfs_fonts.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{asset ('backend/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.print.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/pages/tables/jquery-datatable.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deletearticle(id) {
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: false,
            reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('delete-form-'+id).submit();
            } else if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
            ) {
                swal(
                    'Cancelled',
                    'Your data is safe :)',
                    'error'
                )
            }
        })
    }
</script>
@endpush

//  web.php 
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function (){
    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('article','ArticleController');

});
// Controller file 
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;
use App\Article;
class TagController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.article.index',compact('articles'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.article.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|unique:articles'
        ]);
        $article = new Article();
        $article->name = $request->name;
        $article->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $article->save();
        Toastr::success('Article Successfully Saved :)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $tag = Article::find($id);
        return view('admin.article.edit',compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $article = Article::find($id);
        $article->name = $request->name;
        $article->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $article->save();
        Toastr::success('Article Successfully Updated','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Article::find($id)->delete();
        Toastr::success('Article Successfully Deleted',"Success");
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Route::post('/articles/{id}/delete', 'ArticlesController@destroy')->name('article.destroy');

        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $article = Article::find($id);
            $article->delete();
            return redirect('/articles');
        }

<a class="article-link" href="{{ route('article.destroy',$article->id) }}">Delete This Article</a></p>  

 <form id="delete-form-{{ $article->id }}" action="{{ route('article.destroy',$article->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! I've made my route and destroy() method identical to what you're suggesting, saved everything and refreshed the browser but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: please give me your problem screenshot

Comment: <a class="article-link" href="{{ route('article.destroy',$article->id) }}">Delete This Article</a>

Comment: now try this code i think this code solve your  problem

Comment: That didn't work at all. The error message says: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Route [article.destroy] not defined. (View: C:\Laravel\proj01\resources\views\articles\show.blade.php)
http://localhost:8000/articles/10

Comment: I can understand your peoblem

Answer (score 1):

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Route [article.destroy] not defined. (View: C:\Laravel\proj01\resources\views\articles\show.blade.php)

Make sure you have your routes named

when you use anything like : `route('some.route.name')` there should be a route named accordingly.

In your web i don't see that you named your routes.

```php
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
Route::get('/articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
Route::put('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
Route::post('/articles/{article}/delete', 'ArticlesController@destroy')->name('article.destroy');
```

Notice the `->name('article.destroy');`

Comment: I don't have any named routes. I believe the instructor mentioned them very briefly in passing but said it was just an alternate way to do things that I didn't need to follow. How would I make my code work without named routes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to both responders. Neither answer *completely* solved my problem but you both helped me go in a better direction. I'm awarding Md. the selected-answer checkmark because he probably got me closer.

Here's my final code with a few remarks.

First, here are my routes. The critical change here is that the route which takes me to the destroy method has to use DELETE, not POST:

```
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
Route::get('/articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
Route::put('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
Route::delete('/articles/{id}/delete', 'ArticlesController@destroy')->name('article.destroy');
```

The final version of the ArticlesController is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view ('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
}

public function show(Article $article) 
{
    return view('articles.show', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function create() 
{
    return view('articles.create');
}

public function store() 
{
    //Stores a NEW article
    Article::create($this->validateArticle());
    return redirect('/articles');
}   

public function edit(Article $article) 
{
    return view('articles.edit', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function update(Article $article)
{
    //Updates an EXISTING article
    $article->update($this->validateArticle());
    return redirect('/articles/'.$article->id);
}

public function validateArticle()
{
    return request()->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:30'],
        'author' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:30'],
        'photopath' => ['required', 'min:10', 'max:100'],
        'excerpt' => ['required', 'min:10', 'max:50'],
        'body' => ['required', 'min:50', 'max:500']
    ]);
}

public function delete(Article $article)
{
    return view('articles.delete', ['article' => $article]);
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->delete();
    return redirect('/articles');
}
}
```

The final view utilizes the post method in the form but overrides it to delete via the @method('DELETE') directive and, of course, the @csrf directive needs to be there too:

```
@extends ('layout');

@section ('content');

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            <span class="byline">{{ $article->author}}</span></div>
        <p><img src="{{ $article->photopath}}" alt="An image" class="image image-full"/></p>
        <p style="font-style: italic">{{ $article->excerpt }}</p>
        <p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
        <div>           
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/edit">Edit This Article</a>
            <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{ route('article.destroy', $article->id) }}">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete This Article</button>
            </form>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```